# How to pass a container of derived type to a function needing a container of base type

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, containers

I have a class IBase with only pure virtual functions.  I have another class Derived which inherits IBase.  I have a function in another class that takes a QVector of IBase as a parameter.  When I create a QVector of Derived objects, I can't pass them into this function.  However, I can have a function that takes a IBase object as an argument and pass in a Derived object instance.  Why is this behavior occurring?

Comment: The dupe uses `std::vector` but `Qvector` behaves the same way.

Comment: Because a `Derived` is also a `IBase`, but `QVector<Derived>` is not `QVector<IBase>`.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver